HEIC/HEIF to PNG using NVIDIA hevc_cuvid
OS: Ubuntu
I want to convert heic/heif to png using GPU(not software decoding), mostly to avoid patent issues. While hevc_cuvid + ffmpeg works for h265 video. Since heic/heif are on the same platform hevc, How to convert them to png using "hardware decoding"
